# best practice for SELECT JOIN WHERE query

Tags: mysql, select, join

I've 2 tables first is called `friendship` second is called `user` with following details

`friendship` table fields:

```
uid1, uid2
```

`user` table fields:

```
uid, username, primary_email, f_name, m_name, l_name, avatar, avatar_path
```

Idea is to get all friends details from `user` table when `uid1` on `friendship` table  for example =1 is the following query is the best practice for this idea?

```
SELECT 
   u.uid,
   u.username,
   u.primary_email,
   u.f_name,
   u.m_name,
   u.l_name,
   u.avatar,
   u.avatar_path 
FROM friendship AS f 
LEFT JOIN user AS u ON f.uid2=u.uid 
WHERE f.uid1=1
```

Is it best practice to use join for a single query or use 2 queries one to extract ids from friendship table and the second to extract details of each id from user table eg:-

```
SELECT uid2 from friendship WHERE uid1 =1
```

This query give me array of ids 2,4,6,5,9 then i use it in the following query

```
SELECT * from user WHERE uid IN (2,4,6,5,9)
```

What is the best practice?

Comment: do you want to know the name of the user who has the friends and the friends names? Or only the friends names?

Comment: @bluefeet i want to extract all details of my friends

Answer (score 1):

This query will give you the main person's name and the name of their friends:

```
create table users
(
    uid int,
    username varchar(10),
    fname varchar(10)
)

insert into users values(1, 'test', 'Jim')
insert into users values(2, 'blah', 'Tim')
insert into users values(3, 'xxx', 'Henry')
insert into users values(4, 'nada', 'Bob')

create table friendship
(
    uid1 int,
    uid2 int
)

insert into friendship values (1, 2)
insert into friendship values (1, 3)
insert into friendship values (2, 3)
insert into friendship values (3, 4)

select u2.uid personid
    , u2.fname personname
    , f.uid2 friendid
    , u1.username friendusername
    , u1.fname friendname
from users u1
inner join friendship f
    on u1.uid = f.uid2
left join users u2
    on f.uid1 = u2.uid
```

Results:

[image]

Comment: note that i use the code to extract friends detal for one user not to get all friends of each user

Answer (score 0):

Is your "friendship" status directed or undirected? i.e. if user1 is a friend of user2, implies this that user2 is a friend of user1? If so, you have to change your `ON` and `WHERE` conditions:

```
ON f.uid2 = u.uid OR f.uid1 = u.uid
WHERE u.uid = 1
```

Apart from that, I see nothing wrong with that select query.

Comment: find every friendship have two row 1->2 and 2->1

Comment: @MarcusAdams: using u.uid in WHERE clause needs no OR

Answer (score 0):

If you're sure that you are going to use all of the data, I would say it's best practice to pull the results in a single query. This would require just one trip to the database instead of one for each friend (plus the initial query).

Note, however, that since you are using a LEFT OUTER JOIN from friendship, you could get NULL rows returned if there were no corresponding user record for the uid in the friendship table.

Try an INNER JOIN instead like this:

```
SELECT 
   u.uid,
   u.username,
   u.primary_email,
   u.f_name,
   u.m_name,
   u.l_name,
   u.avatar,
   u.avatar_path 
FROM friendship AS f
JOIN `user` AS u
  ON u.uid = f.uid2
WHERE f.uid1 = 1
```

Comment: note that the second query extract all data needed as i use `IN` so no need to roll through each friend

Comment: yes on query with join vs 2 simple queries note that this query will be used thousand of times

Comment: @Dr_movi, The JOIN is no more work than the two simple queries. Internally, all the same work is being done. Are you hinting that the query cache may be able to make up for the overhead? If so, I have to say that I've never bet on the query cache.